# Harmonic function vanishing at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $u$ is a harmonic function on exterior of a bounded simply connected domain , for simplicity lets say $u\in har(\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{D})$, and $u$ vanishes on both boundary of the unit disk and at infinity.Then can we conclude that $u$ is identically zero in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{D} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Given $\epsilon>0$, find $R$ such that $|u|<\epsilon$ on the circle $|z|=R$. Apply the maximum principle on the annulus $1<|z|<R$. Conclude with $u\equiv 0$ since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.